# Understanding predictions from XGBoost >= 2.0.0

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm looking to understand predictions from XGBoost >= 2.0.0 vs XGBoost < 2.0.0. I built simple models with 1 tree of depth 1 in both XGBoost==2.0.0 and XGBoost==1.7.6 (last version below 2.0.0) and got these trees:

XGBoost==1.7.6

```
0:[f4<5.98499966] yes=1,no=2,missing=1
    1:leaf=-0.531367779
    2:leaf=0.565906286
```

XGBoost==2.0.0

```
0:[f4<5.98999977] yes=1,no=2,missing=2
    1:leaf=-0.463055104
    2:leaf=0.651955843
```

For XGBoost==1.7.6, I get the expected prediction values of sigmoid(-0.531367779) = 0.370198 and sigmoid(0.565906286) = 0.637818.

For XGBoost==2.0.0, I would expect to get sigmoid(-0.463055104) = 0.386261 and sigmoid(0.651955843) = 0.657451. However, instead I get the predictions 0.328116 and 0.598277 respectively. I don't understand why this is the case. Could someone explain what I might be missing?